# WebRTC connections randomly without audio output

Tags: javascript, audio, webrtc

I stumbled on a weird issue in a WebRTC webapp. Here's the setup:
Client A and client B send audio via a send-only WebRTC connections to a SFU.
Client C receives via two receive-only connections to that same SFU the audio streams from client A and B and adds them to two different "audio" elements. The routing between these send and receive connections work properly.

Here's the problem:
On refreshing the page, sometimes client C hears audio from both client A and B. But most of the time client C only hears audio from randomly A or B.
It's happening in both firefox and chrome.

Both connections are receiving data (see graph "bitsReceivedPerSecond") but only one connection is outputting audio. Here an example where C could hear A but not B:

Connection Client A -> C:
[image: Connection with audio output]

Connection Client B -> C:
[image: Connection without audio output]

My understanding of these graphs is that the raw WebRTC connection is working fine (data is sent and received) but somehow a connection does not output audio randomly.

Does anyone have a clue how this can happen?

Here is the "ontrack" callback for adding the streams to the audio elements. The Logs do appear correctly for each connection.

```
gotRemoteStream(e) {
    Logger.log("Remote Streams: #"+e.streams.length);

    if (this.audioElement.srcObject !== e.streams[0]) {
        Logger.log("Received remote Stream with tracks to audio: " + this.audioElement.id);
        this.audioElement.srcObject = e.streams[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: The `totalAudioEnergy` from Client B shows no audible audio, which suggests a sender-side problem in B instead. Could happen e.g. if its input track (microphone?) somehow accidentally got muted (browsers still send packets in this case). Do you ever experience audio from neither?

Comment: the "bitsReceivedPerSecond" is identical to the audio that was sent byClient B. He was talking at the beginning then was silent for a few seconds and then started talking again. So I think the sender-side and the transmission should be fine too. I guess the "totalAudioEnergy" is just the integral of the audioOutputLevel over time

Answer (score 0):

A single audio element can only play one audio track at a time.

You said there were two incoming audio tracks, so if `this.audioElement` is the same element, then each call to `gotRemoteStream` will race setting `srcObject`, one overwriting the other.

This is most likely why you only hear one or the other.

The simplest solution might be to key off the stream associations sent, since they'll tend to differ:

```
const elements = {};

gotRemoteStream({streams: [stream]}) {
    if (!elements[stream.id]) {
      elements[stream.id] = this.audioElementA.srcObject ? this.audioElementB
                                                         : this.audioElementA; 
    }
    elements[stream.id].srcObject = stream;
}
```

This should work for two incoming connections. More than that is left as an exercise.

Comment: As I wrote in my original post "[...] adds them to two different "audio" elements.". I don't use one audio element for two streams

Comment: @DominikVincenz How many "ontrack" callbacks" are involved? I would doublecheck the `this` value, because that would explain the symptom. There's nothing in the code you show to indicate different elements are involved. How do you determine which one gets A vs B?

Comment: for each connection a new object is created which contains the RTCPeerConnection and its target audio element. The code snippet is the callback function in that container class. So there are two objects which contain two different audio elements. Also sometimes Client C can hear both A and B, that would be impossible with one single audio element as you said.
The logs also show two different element ids: Logger.log("Received remote Stream with tracks to audio: " + this.audioElement.id)

Comment: @DominikVincenz You're right, this answer doesn't fit then.